# Tichiyas Hamesim with Gilguls

Tags: resurrection-of-the-dead, reincarnation

We learn that some people come back into this world as Gilgulim (reincarnations) to fix something they didn’t do in their past life. By techiyas Hamesim, which person comes back?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!